# How we can save a image in a folder yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2

When i am uploading a image it is saved in default folder that is /web. I want to save my images in user defined folder.

Answer (score 4):

If its a user defined folder, chances are pretty good you will have to create the directory on the fly, which the [UploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html) method does not do.  For Yii2 I would use the createDirectory() method in the "yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper" class.
ex:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper;

$model->uploaded_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploaded_file');

$unique_name = uniqid('file_');
$model->file_type = $model->uploaded_file->extension;
$model->file_name = $unique_name.'.'.$model->file_type;
$model->file_path = 'uploads/projects/'. $project_id;

BaseFileHelper::createDirectory($model->file_path);

$model->uploaded_file->saveAs($model->file_path .'/'. $model->file_name);
$model->save();
```

Check out [createDirectory](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#createDirectory%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job, if you use model/active form to submit the form (upload image). The key part is saveAs, where the first parameter can be path to file. This includes also [Yii Aliases](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-aliases.md).

```
if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams());
    $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    $file->saveAs('path/to/file');
}
```

Also take a deeper look into [UploadedFile](http://yii2-api.yupe.ru/class-yii.web.UploadedFile.html) class.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but now i know that how to change path..

we can use **chdir('path to folder');**
and it will change our default directory to user defined directory. In YII2

Answer (score 0):

```
//yii 1.1 example
if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName("Shorty[avatar]"))
{
    $basepath = preg_replace('~([\\\]|[\/])protected~s','',Yii::app()->basePath);

    $filename = $basepath ."/images/shorty_images/" . $shorty_model->id . "/";

    if(!file_exists($filename))
        if(!mkdir($basepath ."/images/shorty_images/" . $shorty_model->id, 0777, true))
            throw new CHttpException(404,'Directory create error!');

    $status = $file->saveAs($filename . iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//IGNORE", $file->name));
}
```

Yii 2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it in yii2. I am facing some problem in yii2

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using yii2 file kit. https://github.com/trntv/yii2-file-kit
That more feature

- File upload widget (based on Blueimp File Upload)
- Component for storing files (built on top of flysystem)
- Actions to download, delete, and view (download) files
- Behavior for saving files in the model and delete files when you delete a model

Answer (score -1):

`\Yii::$app->basePath` corresponds to your application folder,for example `\myapp\backend\`.So if you want to save it to `myapp\backend\data`,save it like

```
$file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
$file->saveAs(\Yii::$app->basePath . '/data/'.$file);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $model->password=md5($model->password);
    $model->photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');

    if($model->validate()){
        $model->photo->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->photo->baseName . '.' . $model->photo->extension);
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
}
```

It saves my images in web/uploads folder.