# uploading images in Yii, error $model->save()

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to upload images and add to db file name and now Im stuck, because it wont add entry to db.
Error in debugger is Property `"EeCarTypes.foto" is not defined.`

controllers relavent code:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new EeCarTypes;

        $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/upload/cartypes';
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            mkdir($path);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['EeCarTypes']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['EeCarTypes'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
              {
                $model->image->saveAs( $path . '/adsfasdfadf' );
              }
        }
        $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

view code:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
'CActiveForm',
array(
'id' => 'upload-form',
'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)
);
// ...
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');
echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
echo $form->error($model, 'image');
// ...
echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
$this->endWidget();
```

and model code:

```
  public $image;
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'ee_car_types';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array( 'image', 'file', 'types' => 'jpg, gif, png'),
            array('car_type', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, car_type', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

I think anything else is irelevent here. Please help me :)

Comment: It would help to show the line number that is being reported, and the source code for that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**Replace your view code** 
echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
 with 
 <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>

**In your controller file** 


 if(isset($_POST['EeCarTypes']))
    {
        $rnd = rand(0,9999);
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EeCarTypes'];
        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
        $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";
        $model->image = $fileName;
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EeCarTypes'];
        if($model->save()){
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/upload/cartypes'.$fileName);
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute with the name foto in your model EeCarTypes and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24429436/1764623)

Answer (score 0):

At your model you should create a name property for the image and the field at the database. Then assign the file name to this property at your action method before you call the save(), like this:

```
 $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

 $model->image_name = $file->name;

 //use this if you want to save the file type but first create the image_type property
 $model->image_type = $file->type;

 [...]
```